# Python / Curses - How to print separate items?

Tags: python, python-curses

this code the result screen: foobar (OK)

```
stdscr.addstr(10, 10, "foobar")
```

this code the result screen: **foobar** (OK)

```
stdscr.addstr(10, 10, "foobar", curses.A_REVERSE)
```

But how to get the result screen fo**ob**ar ?

Please consult anyone? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just split this into more than one `addstr()` call.  For example:

```
stdscr.addstr(10, 10, 'fo..ar')
stdscr.addstr(10, 12, 'ob', curses.A_REVERSE)
```

Instead of the dots you can use spaces.  The dots make it easier to see how many characters are between 'fo' and 'ar'.  If the cursor position at the end of the output is important either split the output into three function calls in the order the text parts should appear or set the cursor position explicitly after adding the text.